# Formatting 'the label item' in QGIS layout with bullets and paragraph breaks

Tags: qgis, layouts

I am trying to add bullet points and paragraph breaks (blank line) in the text within 'the label item' in a QGIS layout but I cant seem to do it. Please can anyone help? I cant see anything in the manual or any forums about it.

[image]

Comment: Either define a symbol for line breaks, or use `\n` within single quotation marks.

Comment: Hi Erik. Thanks for getting back to me. I tried that and '\n' is just displayed in the label item text box on its own line. Any further help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: Did you use the "Render as HTML" option ? if not you may try as HTML will allow you to have more control on the formatting of your label

Comment: Hi Erik. I had added an image of how it comes out above. I have also tried the 'render in HTML' and that didn't work either. I have also tried adding it as an expression. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use the "Render as HTML" option of the Label element

For exemple this HTML :

```
Text 1
<ul>
<li>Bullet 1</li>
<li>Bullet 2</li>
<li>Bullet 3</li>
</ul>
Text 2
<ul>
<li>Bullet 1</li>
<li>Bullet 2</li>
<li>Bullet 3</li>
</ul>
```

Render as

[image]

Of course you may use more html tag to get any result you want (for exemple the `<br>` tag is used to add a line break)

This [w3schools internet page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) show how to make list as shown above, explore other page to get more exemple of formatting (this is only one of many internet html guide, I don't know if this one is better than other…)